# Is didReceiveRemoteNotification method always called on a main thread?

Tags: ios, objective-c, multithreading, push-notification

Which thread is [`application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplicationdelegate/1623117-application?preferredLanguage=occ) called on?

There is also a [statement from  docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Notifications/Articles/NotificationCenters.html) that says:

> In a multithreaded application, notifications are always delivered in
> the thread in which the notification was posted, which may not be the
> same thread in which an observer registered itself.

What I want to achieve is that update my UITableView if app is in the foreground (to reload the data).

So I wonder is there a chance the method above is invoked on background thread or I am safe to go without something like

```
if ([NSThread isMainThread]) {
    // do the UI stuff as normal
} else {
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{ /* post notification */ });
}
```

and post a notification by calling some method like this:

```
- (void) helperMethod{

  if([UIApplication sharedApplication].applicationState != UIApplicationStateBackground){
      [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"SOMENAME" object:self];
    }
}
```

rather than using something like this:

```
[self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(myMethod:) withObject:Nil waitUntilDone:NO];
```

Also, I am registering observers in `viewDidLoad` method (and remove them in `viewWillDissapear` method).

Comment: "Unlike the application:didReceiveRemoteNotification: method, which is called only when your app is running in the foreground... " from apple documentation, tells us that this method does not run when your application is in the background. With that said, you know it wont get called when your app is in the background atleast , however. take a look at this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7880742/ios-are-methods-called-by-delegates-and-observers-executed-on-the-main-thread

Comment: @Sneak That statement from the docs, sadly, is sometimes true and sometimes not. I logged everything on disk and it can be clearly seen that application state == background when I receive push notification. Also, a device is not attached to through usb cable to the computer & Xcode. So I am pretty positive that this method is invoked in some cases, and a statement from docs is pretty much incorrect. Also I have some background modes enabled so maybe that is a reason this method gets called sometimes even in background. The only time when this method isn't called, is when I terminate the app.

Comment: Of course a push notification arrives even if I have terminated app, but nothing gets written in the logs, unlike when app is in suspended or background state.

Comment: I have not tested this myself other than reading the documentation. Are you sure you are not running this method? https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiapplicationdelegate/1623013-application , if not, however as in the thread I linked, you should make sure that you are running the correct thread if you want to make sure as you suggested in your example.

Comment: @Sneak Completely positive that I use the method from my title :) Also completely positive in what I've stated above, because I tested it multiple times today, and before, and today I just confirmed. Please be more specific about "correct thread" part.

Comment: The "correct thread" is whatever is correct for you, according to your expectations. The delegate methods should usually be called from the main thread, but you should add a check method as you describe and as described in the link I sent you if you want to make sure it is "correct thread".

Comment: @Sneak Ah of course. I didn't get what you said at first. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

To answer the question, `application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:` was deprecated and replaced with [`application(_:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplicationdelegate/1623013-application). I have observed that this new method is called on the main thread when the app is in the foreground or in the background.

So **yes**, it is called on the `main` thread.

---

However, the rest of your question is confusing.

The `application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:` method is **not related** to the documentation you mentioned (`In a multithreaded application...`). `application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:` is specifically for remote notifications delivered by **APNs**, and the documentation you mentioned is about **NSNotificationCenter**, which is about sending data between between components in your app.